# Why do I get "no main manifest attribute" building a jar from Eclipse antfile?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar

I have:

```
src/Testy.java
projectBuilder.xml
```

Testy.java contains:

```
public class Testy {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hey Dudes");
    }
}
```

And projectBuilder.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Supercool" default="doit" basedir=".">
    <target name="doit" description="Make a jar file">
        <mkdir dir="jars" />
        <jar destfile="jars/Testy.jar" basedir="bin" />
    </target>
</project>
```

When I run the antfile from within Eclipse (after building the project in Eclipse) it builds a jar containing `Testy.class` and a folder `META-INF` containing the file `MANIFEST.MF` which contains:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Created-By: 1.7.0_45-b18 (Oracle Corporation)
```

Running `java -jar Testy.jar` produces:

`no main manifest attribute, in jary\Testy.jar`

Why is that, and what do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted at by a previous answer, [most](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#buildfile) [tutorials](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html) are incomplete. The correct thing to do is modify the `<jar />` tag to this:

```
<jar destfile="jars/Testy.jar" basedir="bin">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Testy" />
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

and then it's possible to run using `java -jar Testy.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which class to be run when you just use -jar. Add a manifest child element to your jar call as mentioned at http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html , and in there designate the name of your main class as documented at http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifest.html .  The attribute name you need is "Main-Class".

Comment: You mean I have to manually create a manifest? I didn't see that step in [this tutorial](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html)

Comment: You have to specify what else you want in the manifest, which *is* in that tutorial. The Ant file contents shown under "Four steps to a running application" show this part exactly.